# Transforming tuple in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, transform

```
(1,
 ['Fast Food',
  'Bakery',
  'Beverages',
  'Burgers',
  'Seafood',
  'Steaks',
  'Tea & Coffee',
  'Dessert',
  'Snacks'],
 'Islamabad',
 'Pakistan',
 ['1', '34'])
```

I have a tuple like this and I want to transform it like this need help:

```
(1,
 ['Fast Food',
  'Bakery',
  'Beverages',
  'Burgers',
  'Seafood',
  'Steaks',
  'Tea & Coffee',
  'Dessert',
  'Snacks',
 'Islamabad',
 'Pakistan',
 '1', '34'])
```

I want a single list and a key of the tuple for e.g (1,[...]),(2,[...]).

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Is the initial structure of the tuple always like your example, or is it some random combination of strings and lists?

Comment: Its always like this both lists size may vary @PatrickHaugh

Comment: @MooingRawr I tried to solve it let me post my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unpack your tuples, combine the lists with the free values, and output new tuples:

```
[(key, list1+strings+list2) for key, list1, *strings, list2 in list_of_tuples]
```

This takes advantage of [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) to get the free strings into a list.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to see what is generating that original list so I could see more cases. But I think this might work for you as long as the key is in the first tuple position.

```
y = (x[0], [i for sublist in x[1:] for i in sublist if isinstance(sublist, list)])
```

Where x is your original tuple. This says: Make a Tuple with the first element being the first element of your original. And second element being a flattened version of the rest of the elements. More information might be very helpful to help you solve this. I imagine making a simple class might be a much cleaner way to represent and work with this data.

```html
>>> x = (1,
...  ['Fast Food',
...   'Bakery',
...   'Beverages',
...   'Burgers',
...   'Seafood',
...   'Steaks',
...   'Tea & Coffee',
...   'Dessert',
...   'Snacks'],
...  'Islamabad',
...  'Pakistan',
...  ['1', '34'])
>>> y = (x[0], [i for sublist in x[1:] for i in sublist if isinstance(sublist, list)])
>>> y
(1, ['Fast Food', 'Bakery', 'Beverages', 'Burgers', 'Seafood', 'Steaks', 'Tea & Coffee', 'Dessert', 'Snacks', '1', '34'])
```